# Magento 2 Installation - 503 (Service Unavailable) Error

Tags: php, magento2, wamp

Tried installing ***Magento 2*** using setup wizard. All the checks were correct and installation was completed till **90%**. After that it did not show any progress for many hours.
When I run the `http://localhost/magento_2`, it takes forever to load and prints 503 error.

[Service Unavailable_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HawqX.png)

As mentioned [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_mod_access_compat.html) I tried debugging as Apache 2.4 changes the way certain directives related to `.htaccess` work.

**Suggested solution on website**

As a user with **root** privileges, enter the following commands:

```
a2enmod access_compat
service <name> restart
```

How do I debug this issue on my local WAMP server and succesfully install Magento 2 with sample data ?

Answer (score 1):

See the browser console for JavaScript and asynchronous HTTP errors.
Also never install Magento on a top-level domain like `localhost` because, in contract to other CMS, Magento does not work properly on a top-level domain.
Use something like `localhost.com` instead.

Comment: localhost.com is not the best name either because it is a real host, which redirects to google BTW

Comment: There is no any JavaScript and asynchronous HTTP errors.In apache error console it shows `PHP Fatal error`: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. but i have already set max_execution_time = 18000 in php.ini file.

Comment: It seems that your `max_execution_time` setting has not been applied. Do call phpinfo() function from the Magento 2 website root and see the actiual `max_execution_time` vaue for Magento 2.

Comment: I have called  `phpinfo()` function and checked `max_execution_time` in it,It  shows me `max_execution_time=18000`.

Comment: memory_limit is also important and should be at least 768M. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html#instgde-prereq-timezone

Answer (score 1):

Could you enable the developer mode from the `.htaccess` file, or you can enable it from the cli

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

to let us see what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Firstly to get rid of the `503 error`:

Clear `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/generation`.
After that assign `777 permission` to `pub/`, `var/` and `app/etc/` folders.

Now, this type of error usually occurs because of the mySQL timeout. You can try increasing mySQL timeout by increasing `max_execution_time` . However, this may or may not work. So you can try installing Magento 2 using `Command line interface`. Command for it is as below:

> sudo php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://myip/myfoldername --backend-frontname=admin --admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=test@example.com --admin-user=admin  --admin-password=mypwd --db-host=localhost --db-name=mydbname --db-user=mydbuser --db-password=mydbpwd

Also some points to note: avoid using localhost URL when installing magento2. You should use IP instead. Before starting installation, assign full permission to `app/etc/`, `var/` and `pub/` folders.

Hope this helps.